# Uploaded files not display in webpages, but the files available in particular path

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have developed a web based application, I am trying to upload a file into particular folder. file has been uploaded successfully. But when i try to display that uploaded file in another page. The uploaded image files are not displayed.

Files are available in the folder, any one please help me.

I have attached my source code and screen below.

**Upload Coding:**
 [Upload Coding][1]

[Display Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM2d0.png)

[File Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp9VB.png)

[Error Message][4]

Comment: try to access the Url with the domain name or localhost

Comment: seems like `src` should be `Admin/Uploads/new/_sum.jpg`

Comment: access by local host only man, thanks  for your interest.

Comment: Is the page where image's not showing named `ViewAllMaster.aspx`??

Comment: @Bikash Singh  no i am just copy and paste that ViewAllMaster,aspx file for testing purpose only. but try this file opened correctly by using url

Comment: Can you please paste the url of the page where image's not shown (i.e. the page of which you've attached screenshot) ?

Comment: kindly check the above attachment display image

Comment: I mean full url something like `http://localhost:57393/bla bla bla.aspx`

Comment: http://localhost:57393/Admin/new.aspx

Comment: @karthikeyan, you've authorization issue with the folder that contains the image. Please check the permission, may be in web.config.

Comment: OK i will check my side , and one more thing the same way  i am using the same thing in another web form in this project is working good .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a url mapping issue. In the ImageURL property try it to "~/Uploads/new/sum.jpg"..

```
 <asp:Image ID="Id" ImageUrl="~/Uploads/new/sum.jpg" runat="server" />
```

Comment: <asp:Image ID="img_fiel" runat ="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Admin/Uploads/new/"+Eval("App_Logo") %>' />

Comment: @karthikeyan. It seems you have Uploads folder inside Admin so try like this. "~/Admin/Uploads/new/sum.jpg"

Comment: yes absolutely, the files are not opens when try to access by url like   http://localhost:57393/Admin/Uploads/new/mobile.png